# Quick sort in C — pointers and memory

Tags: c, algorithm, quicksort, partitioning, swap

I am a computer science freshman and I still have some difficulties when it comes to pointers. I am trying to implement a quick sort program in C.I currently have 2 errors but I am not able to figure out how to fix it.

1. On the main function, when I am calling partition, I got an Incompatible pointer types
2. On the swap function: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x200000007)

```
void swap(int *i, int* j){
    *i = *j;
    *j = *i;
    *i = *j;
}


void partition(int* array[], int size){
    int pivot = size;
    int i = - 1;
    for(int j = 0 ; j < size - 1 ; j++){
        if(array[j] < array[pivot]){
            i++;
            swap(array[i],array[j]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int array[] = {7,2,1,8,6,3,5,4};
    int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    partition(&array,size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up *stooge sort* and check the title. And the indentation - `void swap()`'s looks different.

Comment: @James If an array has N elements then valid indices to access its elements are [0, N-1]

Comment: @James Your swap and partition functions do not make sense.

Comment: Type of `&array` is `int (*)[8]`, not `int *[]`.  Call `partition` as `partition( array, size );` and declare the parameter as `int array[]` or `int *array`.

Comment: regarding: `    void swap(int *i, int* j){
    *i = *j;
    *j = *i;
    *i = *j;
}`  the sequence of statements is: assign *i from *j (now both places contain the initial value of *j and the value that was at *i is lost.  Things do downhill from there.  Suggest either using 'exclusive or' statements or (for simplicity) using a temp variable, like:     void swap(int *i, int* j){
    int temp = *j;
    *j = *i;
    *i = temp;
}`

Comment: in function; `partitition()`  regarding: `swap(array[i],array[j]);`  This passes the actual values.  You want to pass the address of the values  because that is what the `swap()` function is expecting

Comment: in function: `main()` regarding; `partition(&array,size);`  In C, the name of an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  Suggest: `partition( array, size );`  Also, note the appropriate horizontal spacing, for human readability

Comment: Suggest reading: [quicksort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/) which explains the theory behind the algorithm and contains the actual algorithm (in a number of different programming languages)

Answer (score 2):

For starters if an array has N elements then the valid range of indices is `[0, N-1]`

Thus there is an attempt to access memory beyond the array

```
int pivot = size;
int i = - 1;
for(int j = 0 ; j < size - 1 ; j++){
    if(array[j] < array[pivot])
                       ^^^^^^^
```

Your function swap does not make sense.

```
    void swap(int *i, int* j){
    *i = *j;
    *j = *i;
    *i = *j;
}
```

After the first expression statement

```
    *i = *j;
```

the both objects pointed to by the pointers `i` and `j` will have the same value.

The function can be defined the following way.

```
void swap( int *p, int *q )
{
    int tmp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = tmp;
}
```

and called like

```
swap( &array[i], &array[j] );
```

The function partition is also invalid. Apart from the incorrect used algorithm at least its first parameter is declared also incorrectly.

Instead of

```
void partition( int* array[], int size );
```

the function should be declared like

```
void partition( int *array, int size );
```

or more correctly like

```
void partition( int *array, size_t size );
```

and the function should be called like

```
int array[] = {7,2,1,8,6,3,5,4};
size_t size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
partition( array,size );
```

On the other hand, the function `partition` should return the position that divides the array into two parts. So the final function declaration will look like

```
size_t partition( int array[], size_t size );
```

Below there is a demonstrative program that shows how a recursive function quick sort can be written using functions `swap` and `partition`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap( int *p, int *q )
{
    int tmp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = tmp;
}

size_t partition( int a[], size_t n, int pivot )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i != n )
    {
        while ( i != n && a[i] < pivot ) i++;
        while ( i != n && !( a[--n] < pivot ) );

        if ( i != n ) swap( a + i, a + n );
    }

    return i;
}

void quick_sort( int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        size_t pos = partition( a, n - 1, a[n - 1] );
        swap( a + pos, a + n - 1 );

        quick_sort( a, pos );
        quick_sort( a + pos + 1, n - pos - 1 );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 7, 2, 1, 8, 6, 3, 5, 4 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    quick_sort( a, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
7 2 1 8 6 3 5 4 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: Within the partition function, should I call swap like that "swap(&array[i],&array[j]);" ?

Comment: @James Yes, I showed how the function must be called.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in here:

1. The pointer notation has the weird effect that the star comes after the thing it points to, so the `int* array[]` in partition is an array of pointers to integers, while what you call it with in main is a pointer to an array of integers.
2. An array[] is actually a pointer by itself (though with some slightl technical differences, but in general something that accepts a pointer will also accept an array). You are mainly using the array in partition as an array of integers (the `array[j] < array[pivot]` should be a comparison of content, but with an `int* array[]` it is a comparison of address), so you should change it to just being an `int array[]`. Note that this will also help with resolving point 1, as you just need to remove the superflous referencing when you call partition.
3. When you index an array it counts as a dereferencing, so when you call `swap(array[i],array[j])` (assuming you have made the corrections suggested above) you are passing `int`s and not `int*`s, you need to change it to `swap(&array[i],&array[j])`.
4. In swap you are setting both of their values to j's. This happens because the information of what is in i is destroyed when you write over it. There are several ways to handle this, the 2 main ones are saving the information in a temporary variable, and the second is through bit-hacking. Here are 2 examples:

```
void swap(int *i, int* j){
    int temp = *j;
    *j = *i;
    *i = temp;
}
```

An a version using exlusive or:

```
void swap(int *i, int* j){
    *i= *j ^ *i;
    *j= *j ^ *i;
    *i= *j ^ *i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> pointers

I wasn't sure if the question was asking about a pointer based quicksort, so here is an example, using Lomuto partition scheme. In the partition loop, it recurses on the smaller part, and loops back for the larger part, limiting stack space to O(log(n)), but worst case time complexity remains at O(n^2).

```
void QuickSort(int *lo, int *hi)
{
int *pi;
int *pj;
int pv;
int t;
    while (lo < hi){
        pv = *hi;                       /* pivot */
        pi = lo;                        /* partition */
        for (pj = lo; pj < hi; ++pj){
            if (*pj < pv){
                t = *pi;                /*  swap *pi, *pj */
                *pi = *pj;
                *pj = t;
                ++pi;
            }
        }
        t = *pi;                        /* swap *pi, *hi */
        *pi = *hi;                      /*  to place pivot */
        *hi = t;
        if(pi - lo <= hi - pi){         /* recurse on smaller part */
            QuickSort(lo, pi-1);        /*  loop on larger part */
            lo = pi+1;
        } else {
            QuickSort(pi+1, hi);
            hi = pi-1;
        }
    }
}
```